# Colossal objects in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I do for example:

```
dd(Model::query());
```

I receive a colossal output, and not before it freezes the browser, takes minutes to render and chew about 2.5/3 GB of memory.

In this specific case I'm querying a table with 15 rows with 10 columns each.

Is this Yeti footprint something to worry about or it doesn't matter since it is never rendered anyway?

Comment: Happens to me too, I suspect it's the frontend js rendering of `dd()`. If you do a simple `var_dump()` you still get the full (huge) Eloquent object but won't freeze the browser

Comment: Your dumping an Eloquent Builder object. Do you want to see the result of the query? or are you just trying to look at the Builder object ?

Comment: Just trying to look at.